# Viewing memory usage stats of a dotnetcore 2 self contained application on Linux

Tags: c#, linux, .net-core

I have a c# dotnet core 2 application that runs as a systemd service on Linux 14.04 LTS that slows to a crawl after a week or more of running and eventually the application and the OS hang, and I cant even open htop. I used perfcollect and perfview, but was only able to get call stack information. How can I collect memory usage statistics of my application and then display them in a readable format?

Comment: Why don't you run a periodic service that will dump whatever command output you want into a file for you to check in the future? Say you dump htop every 5 minutes and override the file every day / hour depending on your usecase

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could retrieve and log memory usage using System.Diagnostic.Process:

```
var process = Process.GetCurrentProcess();
var currentMemoryUsage = process.WorkingSet64;
```

The value returned by the WorkingSet64 property represents the current size of working set memory used by the process, in bytes.

and the peak memory usage:

```
var peakPhysicalMemoryUsage = process.PeakWorkingSet64;
```

Comment: I was hoping for something that would allow me to see what objects where using how much memory